# Is there a way to define service on controller only

Tags: angularjs

I have this global set up for my angular App module:

```
var App = angular.module('App', [], function ($interpolateProvider) {
    //$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    //$interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```

I include it in all pages with angular stuff.

I then have a controller loaded on a page that requires a service called `'angularFileUpload'`:

```
App.controller('FileUploadController', ['$scope', 'FileUploader', function ($scope, FileUploader) {
```

If i place that service inside the module array, it works fine. Is there a way of just attaching it to this controller instead... this means i do not have to load the script files for every page using this module regardless of if the controllers require the angularfileUpload service or not.

**Edit: regarding the last comment**

If i declare:

```
var App = angular.module('App');
```

How do i then add that service to the module?

Comment: No, you need to declare your module dependencies when you create it. However you don't need to "include it every time", one declaration is enough. In the other pages you can get a reference to your module using `var App = angular.module('App');`

Comment: How do i add the service to the App at that point? I've edited OP

Comment: Angular does not have capability to load on demand, so you have to add as module dependency irrespective.